# Add prefix from another line to each string

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I've a file:

```
# Sequence Data: seqnum=1;seqlen=3142;seqhdr="GUT_GENOME148255_1"
>1_59_1276_-
>2_1339_1842_-
>3_1873_2436_-
>4_2470_2928_-
# Sequence Data: seqnum=2;seqlen=3085;seqhdr="GUT_GENOME148255_2"
>1_3_266_-
>2_256_1038_-
# Sequence Data: seqnum=3;seqlen=3050;seqhdr="GUT_GENOME148255_3"
>1_22_1062_-
>2_1072_1746_-
>3_1767_3017_-
# Sequence Data: seqnum=4;seqlen=2934;seqhdr="GUT_GENOME148255_4"
>1_83_436_-
>2_438_1430_-
>3_1432_1872_-
>4_1986_2933_+
```

I'd like to add the number corresponding to `seqnum` to every row starting with `>`, so that it'd look like this:

```
# Sequence Data: seqnum=1;seqlen=3142;seqhdr="GUT_GENOME148255_1"
>1-1_59_1276_-
>1-2_1339_1842_-
>1-3_1873_2436_-
>1-4_2470_2928_-
# Sequence Data: seqnum=2;seqlen=3085;seqhdr="GUT_GENOME148255_2"
>2-1_3_266_-
>2-2_256_1038_-
# Sequence Data: seqnum=3;seqlen=3050;seqhdr="GUT_GENOME148255_3"
>3-1_22_1062_-
>3-2_1072_1746_-
>3-3_1767_3017_-
# Sequence Data: seqnum=4;seqlen=2934;seqhdr="GUT_GENOME148255_4"
>4-1_83_436_-
>4-2_438_1430_-
>4-3_1432_1872_-
>4-4_1986_2933_+
```

The procedure should go over the entire file. I suspect this could be done with `awk` but my efforts to apply it are useless.

Comment: Regarding `my efforts to apply it are useless.` - [edit] your question to show one such effort so we can help you. See [ask].

Comment: @EdMorton exactly, always sequential starting from 1, no gaps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```bash
awk '
  /^# Sequence Data/ {n++} 
  /^>/ {sub(/>/, ">" n "-")}
  1
' file
```

Self-explanatory I think.

Comment: You don't need the `/^>/` , just `{sub(/^>/,">"n)}`. No point looking for `>` twice.

Comment: What if the sequence line happens to have a ">". I do want to filter the lines for modification.

Comment: Note the `^` I added to the front of the regexp in the `sub()` - with that it'll only do the replacement if there's a `>` at the start of the line, just like `/^>/` is testing for.

Answer (score 5):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/seqnum=/h;/^>/G;s/^>(.*)\n[^0-9]+([0-9]+).*/>\2-\1/' file
```

Make a copy of the line containing `seqnum`.

For every line beginning `>`, append the copy and using pattern matching and back references, format as required.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to extract the `seqnum=` and can't guarantee that the numbers increase  monotonically, try

```
awk '/^# Sequence Data:/ {
    s=$0; sub(/.*seqnum=/, "", s); s += 0 }
  /^>/ { sub(/^>/, ">" s "-" } 1' file
```

The addition of 0 to `s` forces the value to be a number, which also trims off the non-numeric tail from the value we originally capture (`$0` is the entire current input line).

Comment: @HatLess I do not have the power to single-handedly close anything, unless it's a duplicate of an existing question in a tag where I have a gold badge. In this case, another user had already provided an answer which however had some assumptions which might not hold for future visitors. I admit that it's a tricky matter to draw the line exactly between lack of demonstrated effort and simply being new.

Comment: Tricky or simply when convenient?

Comment: If you want to discuss this further, probably post on [meta]. Lack of effort is not as such a close reason any longer, though it once was.